# Populate Text Fields from Dropdown menu Selections

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a fillable Pdf document. I need to populate 4 text fields based on selection in drop down menu.
I'm getting error " missing : after property id " on line function SetFieldValues(cDeptName) {

I got the script from here:
https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/change_another_field
And changed according to my fields names.

My dropdown menu is called Diameter (where I have about 10 values). When one is selected, it will populate 4 fields (Max Major Diameter, Min Major Diameter, Max Pitch Diameter, and Min Pitch Diameter). Every Diameter Value has 4 different values.

I would appreciate some help.
This is my first script, and I want to learn.

Thank you.

Sincerely,
Alex

```
var Diameter = { 1/2":{ MaxMajorDiameter: "0.4985", 
MinMajorDiameter: "0.4876", 
MaxPitchDiameter: 0.485", 
MinPitchDiameter: "0.4435" }, 
5/8":{ MaxMajorDiameter: "0.6234", 
MinMajorDiameter: "0.6113", 
MaxPitchDiameter: "0.5644", 
MinPitchDiameter: "0.5589" }, 
3/4":{ MaxMajorDiameter: "0.7482", 
MinMajorDiameter: "0.7353", 
MaxPitchDiameter: "0.6832", 
MinPitchDiameter: "0.6773" }, 
7/8":{ MaxMajorDiameter: "0.8731",  
MinMajorDiameter: "0.8592", 
MaxPitchDiameter: "0.8009", 
MinPitchDiameter: "0.7946" }, 
1":{ MaxMajorDiameter: "0.998", 
MinMajorDiameter: "0.983", 
MaxPitchDiameter: "0.9168", 
MinPitchDiameter: "0.91" }, 
1 1/4":{ MaxMajorDiameter: "1.2478", 
MinMajorDiameter: "1.2314", 
MaxPitchDiameter: "1.155", 
MinPitchDiameter: "1.1476" }}; 
function SetFieldValues(cDeptName) { 
this.getField("MaxMajorDiameter").value = DeptData[cDeptName].MaxMajorDiameter; 
this.getField("MinMajorDiameter").value = DeptData[cDeptName].MinMajorDiameter; 
this.getField("MaxPitchDiameter").value = DeptData[cDeptName].MaxPitchDiameter;
this.getField("MinPitchDiameter").value = DeptData[cDeptName].MinPitchDiameter;
```

}

Comment: Please have another go at formatting your code, see here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. You can expand the section, giving you more options to see, i.e. using backticks.

Comment: I'm having a syntax error: Missing : after property id on line: function SetFieldValues(cDeptName) {

Answer (score 0):

```
var theData = {
'-' : {
"mmin" : "-",
"mmax" : "-",
"pmin" : "-",
"pmax" : "-",
},
'1/2"' : {
"mmin" : "0.4985",
"mmax" : "0.4876",
"pmin" : "0.4485",
"pmax" : "0.4435",
},
'5/8"' : {
"mmin" : "0.6234",
"mmax" : "0.6113",
"pmin" : "0.5644",
"pmax" : "0.5589",
},
'3/4"' : {
"mmin" : "0.7482",
"mmax" : "0.7353",
"pmin" : "0.6832",
"pmax" : "0.6773",
},
'7/8"' : {
"mmin" : "0.8731",
"mmax" : "0.8592",
"pmin" : "0.8009",
"pmax" : "0.7946",
},
'1"' : {
"mmin" : "0.998",
"mmax" : "0.983",
"pmin" : "0.9168",
"pmax" : "0.91",
},
'1 1/4"' : {
"mmin" : "1.2478",
"mmax" : "1.2314",
"pmin" : "1.155",
"pmax" : "1.1476",
},
'1 1/2"' : {
"mmin" : "1.4976",
"mmax" : "1.4794",
"pmin" : "1.3893",
"pmax" : "1.3812",
},
'1 3/4"' : {
"mmin" : "1.7473",
"mmax" : "1.7268",
"pmin" : "1.6174",
"pmax" : "1.6085",
},
'2"' : {
"mmin" : "1.9971",
"mmax" : "1.9751",
"pmin" : "1.8528",
"pmax" : "1.8433",
},
'2 1/4"' : {
"mmin" : "2.2471",
"mmax" : "2.2251",
"pmin" : "2.1028",
"pmax" : "2.0931",
},
'2 1/2"' : {
"mmin" : "2.4969",
"mmax" : "2.4731",
"pmin" : "2.3345",
"pmax" : "2.3241",
},
'2 3/4"' : {
"mmin" : "2.7468",
"mmax" : "2.723",
"pmin" : "2.5844",
"pmax" : "2.5739",
},
'3"' : {
"mmin" : "2.9968",
"mmax" : "2.973",
"pmin" : "2.8344",
"pmax" : "2.8237",
},

}
```

Comment: I succeeded in writing a working script. The script works only when the pdf is viewed using Acrobat. However, when opened with any Internet Explored, dependable fields from drop down menu aren't populated, the script doesn't work. I tried to Google the problem, but no luck. Can someone please help me   move me in the right direction, to learn how to fix this?

Comment: When the PDF is opened in Chrome, it uses Chrome's built in PDF viewer. All the browsers are going that way. The script is not working (the fields aren't populated, when a value is selected from the drop down menu).

I'm almost positive this is true, that web pdf viewer cannot use the script I use in the pdf form, and the pdf cannot be properly filled using web pdf viewer.